# Unhandled Exception: Assertion failed: "Platform interfaces must not be implemented with `implements`" (Flutter, Dart isolate)

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I try to parse data from a Firestore QuerySnapshot to my data model called "Post". In order to increase the performance I try using dart isolates using compute()

I have this code here:

```
static Future<List<Post>> getPosts(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
  return await compute<QuerySnapshot, List<Post>>(_calculate, snapshot);
}
```

Top-level function:

```
List<Post> _calculate(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snap in snapshot.docs) {
    //...Can't continue because this gives the error
  }
  return [];
}
```

Picture of the error:

[image: error]

Is it even possible to handle data types other than int, String, etc.? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you manage to do that? I have the same issue